Where to place virtual base class copy assignment operator in derived class copy assignment operator?
In an old closed-source codebase I came across a comment where the author suggests placing virtual base class copy assignment after those of immediate base classes or that it can result in "incorrect semantics".
Searching "where to place virtual base class copy assignment inside derived class copy assignment operator" does not yield any answer, which seems to suggest I might have hit a less traversed corner of C++? The codebase is pretty old (1990s), so I am not even sure if the requirements have changed in the meanwhile, in newer C++ standards/compilers (read gcc).

I'm quite sure there are no rules in C++ regarding that. I guess the comment is about this specific implementation (as in, changing the order will break this code, don't try it)?

I'm curious. Can you show relevant code snippets and the full comment?

Instead of some old codebase's guidelines, you should refer to core c++ guidelines. C++ has changed drastically from its older version in the 1990s(which the codebase uses)

Can't post the code unfortunately. But could it be related to copying the pointer to the virtual table? Like if the intermediate base classes in a diamond inheritance could overwrite the vptr of virtual base successively? Placing the virtual base class copy operator at the end will make sure that it's vptr at the end is correct?  That's the only thing I can think of, but not sure in a real world example how that could blow things up, because everything with vptr has to do with execution of some virtual function. And in most of the copy assignment operations one doesn't call virtual functions..

Vtables and vptrs should not be of concern unless you write a compiler. Besides, assignment operator shouldn't even modify vptr, you already have an object of type X, you cannot change type of object dynamically.
